# Shortest path between nodes in netlogo using nw extension

Tags: netlogo, move, shortest-path, shapefile, identification

I want to find the shortest path between two nodes - slocation and new-location - in a network of links

I have several slocation and new-location. One slocation for each citizen with some age, sex, and other characteristics, and one new-location for each node close to a work building.

I could identify these nodes with colors - see image.

However, I could not identify the shortest path between each slocation (for each citizen) and newlocation.

I got the following error: **BUT-FIRST expected input to be a string or list but got the TRUE/FALSE false instead.**
when I run these lines of code:

```
  ask slocation 
  [set path but-first nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to new-location weight]
```

**Is this because I have several slocation and new-location? 
should I introduce and *foreach* variable to calculate the shortest path for each citizen?** I tried already only with one citizen and still this part of the code is not capable to find the path

**I think the error is that the nodes slocation and new-location are not connected with a single link. The citizens have to select the shortest path created by links connecting these nodes to reach the new-location. Someone knows how to do this?**

Here, it is my other part of the code:

```
    breed [citizens citizen] 
    breed [nodes node] 

    links-own [weight]

    to go
    set-timekeeper
    ask citizens
    [find-day-activities]
    end

    to set-timekeeper
    tick
    if (counter = 2) [set timekeeper 2] ;From 7:00 AM to 9:00 AM
    end

    to find-day-activities
    if (timekeeper = 2) [Do_7AM_9AM]
    end

    to Do_7AM_9AM
    if (sex = 0 and age = 1 and employment = 0 and household-size = 0) 
    [shortest-distance]
    end

    to shortest-distance
    let slocation min-one-of nodes [distance myself]
    ask slocation [set color yellow]
    let new-location one-of nodes with-min [distance one-of workbuildings]
    ask new-location [set color blue]
    ask links [set weight link-length]
    let path nobody
    ask slocation 
    [set path but-first nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to new-location weight]
    ask turtle-set path [ set color yellow ]
    end
```

If there is any question about how I create the road network from a shapefile, this is the code:

```
to make-road-network
  clear-links
  let first-node nobody
  let previous-node nobody
  foreach gis:feature-list-of roads [ polyline ->
    foreach gis:vertex-lists-of polyline [ segment ->
      foreach segment [ coordinate ->
        let location gis:location-of coordinate
        if not empty? location [
          create-nodes 1 [
            set color green
            set size 1
            set xcor item 0 location
            set ycor item 1 location
            if first-node = nobody [
              set first-node self
            ]
            if previous-node != nobody [
              create-link-with previous-node
            ]
            set previous-node self
          ]
        ]
      ]
      set previous-node nobody
    ]
  ]
ask links [set color red
           set thickness 1]
end
```

[image]